# Problema con react-native-firebase al ejecutarlo en android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

Estoy trabajando en react-native, he instalado [react-native-firebase](http://rnfirebase.io/docs/), en iOS no tuve problema pero estoy intentando el comando react-native run-android, y este es el error que devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguí todos los pasos de la documentación, no se que pude haber hecho mal, intento seguir los pasos que recomienda el WARNING actualizando el android/app/build.gradle, así:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

Y entonces obtengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi package.json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Hola tienes un problema con **link references** para poder solucionar este error despues de ejecutar `npm install react-native-firebase` podrias usar `react-native link react-native-firebase` pero en la mayoria de casos no quedan bien los link de las dependencias. Te recomiendo que todo este procesos lo hagas desde **Android Studio** y no desde tu editor de texto convencional, sigue las indicaciones de esta guia de instalacion oficial de **react-native-firebase** https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/installation/android

Answer (score 0):

complementado la respuesta de @George Rozo, es sumamente recomendable que utilices Android Studio, ya que en algunas ocasiones el problema puede que no sean los psquetes instalados sino tal vez alguna configuración con tu proyecto.

Te recomiendo revises con android studio y rectifiques lo siguiente:

compile emplazarlo por Implementation, 
de igual manera verifica la version de sdk con la que estan trabajando tus paquetes.

y trata de instalar de nuevo el paquete `npm i react-native-firebase`